# Targeting specific Wordpress posts in a loop

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to target individual posts so I can change the css (title tags, padding, etc) of specific posts. My Wordpress site currently generates the posts in a loop.

index.php code (brings in content.php which has 'post' code)

```
<div>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php
                get_template_part( 'content' );
            ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
        </div>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

content.php code (gets post-title, category, and sets post-thumbnail to background-image)

```
 <?php
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
  $thumbnail_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(     get_the_ID()), 'my-fun-size' );
  $thumbnail_url = $thumbnail_data[0];
}
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" style="background-image:url('<?  php echo $thumbnail_url ?>')" <?php post_class('container-fluid'); ?> >

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php      the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_category(', '); ?>
  </div>    
</div>

</article><!-- /#post -->
```

functions.php (setting image size)

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size('my-fun-size', 'thumbnail');
```

The output is 'rows' 100% width with the title, category and background-image (feature-image). Stacked on top of each other. I want to be able to target the text and bg-image of different posts to make them each look different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the best way to to this is by [adding a custom field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) inside your posts, then, in your templates, you call that custom field this way:

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name_of_your_custom_field', true);
```

this must be inside the loop.

Comment: how will i be able to target each one (like if I had 7 posts i'll need seven unique custom fields

Comment: Same way, when you add the custom field, you can add a custom value for each post

Comment: I've never done that before so I'm a bit confused. How would the code look? since it's generated in a loop wouldn't it keep generating the same custom field for each post?

Comment: Or are you suggesting a new 'content - ____ .php' for each post

Comment: Look inside your admin/post/add new, you will see a module called custom field, you add your values there, then you use `get_post_meta` to get that value in your templates, [read this info](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) .

Comment: ok perfect thank you. Just confused since the posts are created in a loop, if I name my custom field 'cs-field' for example, since its looped, I would have a bunch of posts with 'cs-feild' as a custom field and i'd be where I am